# two definition of the Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I read the definition of Poisson process in Shereve's "Stochastic Analysis" which is constructed explicitly:

(A)

step 1:construct iid exponential r.v.$\tau_i$ with parameter $\lambda$

step 2:define $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \tau_k$.

step 3:define $N(t)=\max\{n:S_n\le t\}$

then $N(t)$ is called a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$

But I wonder if there is a equivalent way to define the Poisson process according to its property

for example

(B)

$N(t)$ is a stochastic process,which satisfies

(1)counting process (nonnegative integer valued,increasing) with $N(0)=0$

(2)independent and stationary increment

(3)$\mathbb P(N(t)=n)=\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}$

I wonder if the two definition (A) and (B) are equivalent.

$A\Rightarrow B$ is easy.

Now consider why $B\Rightarrow A$:

first I proved that each time $N(t)$ jump at most 1 each time according to B(3) and stationary increments.

then I can construct $S_k=$the time when $k$th jump happens

then define $\tau_k=S_k-S_{k-1}$

now I want to prove that $\tau_k$ is iid exponential distributed.

But I can only prove that $\tau_1$ is exponential distributed,how to do the next?

Comment: Can't you use your second hypothesis, (2), for that?

Comment: (also, related to your otiginal question -- not the proof itself, but "is there an eqauivalent way to define [..]". See Definition 2.20 in [Probability and Stochastics (Erhan Cinlar), Chap 5, p.188](http://books.google.com/books?id=7VtAx56r8CAC&lpg=PA171&pg=PA188#v=onepage&q&f=false), and the paragraph which follows.)